# How to make a shell script setup file see my conda environment

Tags: deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to apply the CyCADA paper: https://github.com/jhoffman/cycada_release/tree/8629c03fe78a72d4aaa0be1a434018f8600dfae4

I'm trying to run the "train_cycada.sh", but I get an error "No module named 'torch'", even though i have torch on my conda environment. I guess the problem is that bash on windows doesn't see the conda environment .... anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: probably your python path isn't on Conda. Can you run `which python` to see where the python path is located?

Comment: where should I run this command?

Comment: Terminal/command line